# Why Wine takes so much disk space on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

```
sudo apt install winehq-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libblkid1:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libexif12:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu60:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
  libmount1:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libunistring2:i386
  libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 wine-devel wine-devel-amd64
  wine-devel-i386:i386
Suggested packages:
  gvfs:i386 rng-tools:i386 libgd-tools:i386 gnutls-bin:i386 gphoto2:i386 gpm:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools:i386
  jackd2:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386 unixodbc-bin:i386 libportaudio2 libportaudio2:i386
  opus-tools:i386 hplip:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386 | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386 libsasl2-modules-otp:i386
  libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 sndiod:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libblkid1:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libexif12:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu60:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
  libmount1:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libunistring2:i386
  libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 wine-devel wine-devel-amd64
  wine-devel-i386:i386 winehq-devel
0 upgraded, 128 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 91.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 777 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

While it takes only ~25MiB on Puppy Linux as a `.pet` package?

Comment: Because the system you use is 64-bit, wine is 32-bit so all the 32-bit crap needs to be installed.  Why the pet is 25Mb is beyond our scope but it is an installer so will be compressed.

Comment: Also you're using the -devel or development version, which causes more libraries with debugging tools to be used (which use extra ram too)